# Change color of Font Awesome icons in Zurb Foundation 6.3 with css hover

Tags: hover, zurb-foundation, font-awesome

I want to change the color of the circles in my stacked Font Awesome social icons (ie., the icons are on top of circles) on pages in Zurb Foundation 6.3, using the hover property to go from a gray to a red color.

I've researched different solutions but nothing works. (I understand you can't specify the inline-block property to align the icons because it keeps the hover property from working, so I used ul and li tags instead.)

Is the problem because I'm using Font Awesome in Foundation rather than in Bootstrap?  I can't find any documentation on this; I assume it will work with Foundation.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve J.

Here's my code:

CSS:

```
.social fa-circle {
color: #808080;
}

.social fa-circle:hover {
color: #990000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns social">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="">
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x style="color: gray;"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" 
            style="font-size: 1.2rem;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-fw fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="font-size: 1.25rem;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" ></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="font-size: 1.2rem;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're missing the periods for the fa classes. try:

```
.social .fa-circle {
color: #808080;
}

.social .fa-circle:hover {
color: #990000;
}
```

Comment: Good catch; that was very simple.  However, it didn't work. What the code has been doing (and is still doing) is making my icon circles display a maroon color, which then turn to red on hover.  That looks fine and I can live with it, but it isn't what I coded.  I wanted grey circles that turn to maroon on hover.  Btw, my Font Awesome custom code in the <head> is: <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/75933ebc7c.js"></script>

Comment: Then it might be other styles overriding these declarations. Have you tried using !important ? Post a url and we might be able to help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: I tried adding !important into the hover CSS, but it didn't work:                                                   
                                                                                                           .social .fa-circle:hover {  
 color: #990000 !important;
}

Comment: I've been working on this in a second version of the site that I already uploaded.  In my first (uploaded) version, I used Building Blocks from Foundation to make the social buttons, as well as a fullscreen slider.  Both are on the index page, and neither work correctly.  If you'd like to see this first version for this site and think you could troubleshoot both, it's on my general site -- here's the URL: http://chicagocreativedirector.com/hm/index.html

Comment: ah, your problem is that the styles for the hover styles in links are overiding the color of the icons. try something like .social a:hover .fa-circle{ color: #990000;}. You might need even more specificity.